# Cannot update ubuntu 15.04 or install any package

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, update-manager

Whenever I try to update or install a package this happens:( I have no idea how to fix this)

```
    anurag@anurag-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11
Suggested packages:
  visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/36.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 284 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up udev (219-7ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service rc.local if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rc.local and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service gdm at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rc.local and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: did you find a solution?